# Htaccess remove php file & get from url

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm trying to remove the php file & the get request from the URL so it looks a lot cleaner but when I load my index it just shows a blank page.

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /fetch.php?i=$1 [L]
```

Thats the rule i'm using so remove `/fetch.php?i` from the url to leave the trailing get request info.

Example full url `doamin.com/fetch.php?i=bOkU1.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

This is the basic rule to hide fetch.php from the URL. 
Put this in your root .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /fetch.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to make any changes, I've added it but nothings changed

Comment: @user1745014 what php version you are using ?